# Xcode 4 iOS app validation failed -- claims my version is not higher . . . but it IS higher

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios, validation

The validation failure message error is this:

"The Key CFBundleVersion in the info.plist file must contain a higher version than that of the previously uploaded version."

Well, it IS higher.  The old version was 2.21, and the new one is 2.3.  I found a post online from someone who said this problem was solved when they deleted all the other info.plist files in their project . . . well, that isn't really an option as I have 8 targets in my project.  But just to be sure, I updated them all to say version 2.3.  But it didn't help.

Comment: Paul is right. @Macrick3, they are not using a floating-point-scheme.

Comment: version numbers arent regular decimals. You can also have 3.21.2 or whatever. Every part of the version is valuated on its own.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, Paul (comments above) is right.

In this case, 21 > 3.

You're assuming that the version number is a floating point number, but it's not. It's a series of integers separated by a period.

So 2.21 is greater than 2.3.

See here: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjCTutorial/08Configuring/08Configuring.html

Answer (score 4):

Change it to 2.30.

30 > 21

3 < 21

Had the same problem a few weeks ago !

Comment: Yeah me too!  That will fix it